# Why is VLAN needed when we can have different broadcast id?

Tags: networking

Apart from security reason I have always read VLAN is used to handle large amount of broadcast.

But say we are in 192.168.0.0/24 so by that we know broadcast ip is 192.168.0.255 . It mean all all the device broadcast at 192.168.0.255 for arp etc isn't it?

So if we are facing broadcast problem we can use 192.168.1.0/24 which mean broadcast ip is 192.168.1.255 meaning all client using this network will broadcast  at 192.168.1.255 meaning they are not doing anything to 192.168.0.0/24 network isn't it.

So the question is if people are in different network meaning they have different broadcast ip how the problem of broadcast came. For 24 mask there is 254 host so 254 host is problem then we can use smaller subnet like 25 etc isn't it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A switch without VLANs would need to send the broadcasts for different IP subnets to all ports anyway, because it has no notion of subnets and doesn't know which port operates on which subnet. It operates on layer 2 of the [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model), but subnets are defined on layer 3. [VLAN tags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_LAN) are handled on layer 2.